# IsolatedStorageException when reading from file in Android App

Tags: c#, android, json, file, unity-game-engine

I am developing a simple game in Unity and so far it works perfectly on PC. However when launching it in Android I am getting this error:

> I/Unity (26449): IsolatedStorageException: Could not find a part of
>   the path
>   "/mnt/asec/es.uca.gii.dsh.traducinante-1/base.apk/Resources/items.json".

I don't really get what this is about but it seems like it's not reading from the json. This totally messes with my application because it's not getting the data I need to initialize pretty much everything I need for the game.

Here's the piece of code here this is happening:

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/items.json");
```

What am I missing? How can it work on PC but not at all on Android? How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it changing the way I am accessing the resource:

```
TextAsset txtAsset = Resources.Load("items") as TextAsset;
string jsonString = txtAsset.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach:

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/yourFileName.json", FileMode.Open);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    //do whatever you want
}
```